# Expand/Collapse Mat-Expansion-Panels Without Button or Toggle

Tags: angular, angular-material

Just a question.  Can Mat-Expansion-Panels be expanded or collapsed using an event other than a `<button>` or  toggle?  I am trying to collapse the panels when I clear a text field

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can call `MatExpansionPanel.open/.close()` to open/close a single panel.

you can call `MatAccordion.openAll/.closeAll()` to open/close all panels.

these actions do not need to be in response to some button click or anything really.

refer to [API Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a boolean variable on the clear text field and use [expanded] to expand/collapse the panel like the following -

```
 <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="yourVariable">
//code
</mat-expansion-panel>
```